# Parsing log entries using awk

Tags: parsing, awk

I get the below logs:

```
2013-10-24 18:35:49,728 ERROR [xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.xx] (xx.xx.xx.xx.xx) Manila Olongapo Leyte Tacloban has updated their subscriber details. But, the Regional Account Update interface call has failed for the following Local Registries: <br/>Visayas<br/>Data between LRA and the above Local Registries is out of synch as a result.
```

I want the result input to be in the below format. What is the better way to do this — using `awk` or `sed` perhaps? Please advise.

```
$Province$ has updated their subscriber details. However, the Customer Account Update interface call has failed for the following Land Registries:
$Region Name$
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  Is the incoming record on 3 lines? Do you want `$Province$` and `$Region Name$` to appear in the output? Is it accidental or deliberate that the input contains 'Regional Account' but the output contains 'Customer Account'. Does the list 'Manila Olongapo Leyte Tacloban' vary?

Comment: This log parser you want will fail if $Region Name$ or if $Province$ does not follow the same number of fields you example have. Please edit your question with more accurate requisites.

Answer (score 1):

Considering just your ONE line of example, and just to p̶o̶o̶r̶l̶y̶ answer your question, here it goes:

```
echo '2013-10-24 18:35:49,728 ERROR [xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.xx] (xx.xx.xx.xx.xx) Manila Olongapo Leyte Tacloban has updated their subscriber details. But, the Regional Account Update interface call has failed for the following Local Registries: <br/>Visayas<br/>Data between LRA and the above Local Registries is out of synch as a result.'  | awk '{print $6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,"However, the Customer",$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,"Land",$28,substr($29,6,7)}'
```

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty easy to do in `sed`:

```
sed -r '
    s#(^.*\) |<br/>Data.*$)##g;
    s/But/However/;
    s/Regional/Customer/;
    s/Local/Land/;
    s# <br/>#\n#
' input.log
Manila Olongapo Leyte Tacloban has updated their subscriber details. However, the Customer Account Update interface call has failed for the following Land Registries:
Visayas
```

Comment: OP asked about awk, not sed.